# Is there a limit to how long I can hold items in my mailbox?

Tags: pocket-frogs

I know that I can only hold a maximum of 8 items in my mailbox in *Pocket Frogs*. Right now, I'm using it as kind of a pseudo-storage while I make more money to be able to afford to buy more habitats. The ingame Help section doesn't mention anything about there being a limit to how long you can keep items in your mailbox, but I want to make sure that there truly isn't such a limit.

I have a few frogs that I have found and that have been sent to me that I'm leaving in my mailbox because I don't currently have room for them. Is it safe to leave items there, or do I risk them being accidentally deleted if I let them linger for too long?

Answer (score 1):

Items will remain in the mailbox indefinitely until they are either removed or placed in a habitat.